# How do I use curly braces to create multiple directories in a single command via "shelljs"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ubuntu-18.04, shelljs

If you run this command in a Linux terminal:

```
mkdir -p ./dist/{articles,scripts,stylesheets}
```

It'll create the following folder tree (in the current directory):

```
dist
|- articles
|- scripts
|- stylesheets
```

The problem occurs when I try to do the same using the [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) npm package.

For example, calling the following function:

```
shell.mkdir("-p", "./dist/{articles,scripts,stylesheets}");
```

Results in the following file tree being created:

```
dist
|- {articles,scripts,stylesheets}
```

In other words, it's a folder called `dist` that contains a subfolder called `{articles,scripts,stylesheets}`.

I've tried escaping the curly braces, like this:

```
shell.mkdir("-p", "./dist/\{articles,scripts,stylesheets\}");
```

It didn't work, so I doubled down and escaped the backslash:

```
shell.mkdir("-p", "./dist/\\{articles,scripts,stylesheets\\}");
```

That didn't work either, so I doubled down again and added an escaped backslash before the escaped backslash:

```
shell.mkdir("-p", "./dist/\\\\{articles,scripts,stylesheets\\\\}");
```

Which didn't work, but it did create a folder with a different name:

```
\\{articles,scripts,stylesheets\\}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can JavaScript loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*shelljs* `mkdir()` command takes as parameter a list or an array of directory names. It will not attempt to execute any command or sequence builder utility provided by *bash*, as we can see in [source](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/blob/9237f66c52e5daa40458f94f9565e18e8132f5a6/src/mkdir.js#L55) code. So there is no point to try to escape the braces.

Instead you could send the raw command with [`exec()`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback):

```
shell.exec("bash -c 'mkdir -p ./dist/{articles,scripts,stylesheets}'")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but this solution doesn't work, it's still creating a sub folder called `{articles,scripts,stylesheets}`.

Comment: You're seeing different results because it relies on undefined behavior. `shelljs` invokes `sh`, so this snippet will work on macOS and CentOS where `sh` is `bash`, while it fails on Debian/Ubuntu and Alpine where `sh` is `dash` and BusyBox `ash` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to rewrite brace expansion using loops or similar:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
for(var dir of ["articles", "scripts", "stylesheets"]) {
  shelljs.mkdir("-p", "./dist/" + dir)
}
```

This is fast, robust and portable.

Equivalently, you can use a [third party library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braces) that expands them for you:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
const braces = require('braces')
shell.mkdir("-p", braces("./dist/{articles,scripts,stylesheets}", {expand: true}))
```

The literal way is to explicitly invoke Bash, since brace expansion is a bash feature:

```
shelljs.exec("bash -c 'mkdir -p ./dist/{articles,scripts,stylesheets}'")
```

This is slow, fragile and non-portable because it requires two invocations of two Unix shells and two corresponding levels of escaping.

The point of `shelljs` is to replace such code with pure JS implementations so that it requires zero invocations of zero shells, so this entirely defeats the purpose of using it in the first place.